# Tools for mass renaming Ruby classes and their files & test files

Tags: ruby

I am looking for tools or good methods for renaming files & classes in Ruby when renaming classes.

Say I have class Foo, in foo.rb with foo_test.rb and I want to rename it to NewFoo, new_foo.rb and new_foo_test.rb.  Any usage of Foo in other ruby files would be replaced to NewFoo.

Normally I do this using a bit of Bash and VIM (for replacing the class name).

I just wondered if there is a good tool out there (IDE independent or VIM based) which helps with this.

Answer (score 1):

This can certainly be scripted. There was a generator plugin at some point to do that (https://github.com/hiroshi/script-refactor#readme) but it is very old, and will probably not work today. Update: this https://github.com/jcrisp/rails_refactor looks a lot more recent, so can probably work.

Now, a good editor and/or a bit of regexp-fu should bring you quite far. After all, Ruby source code is only text, and model classes are quite easy to identify, so you could probably roll out your own quite fast. I did some rename but always manually (faster than writing a script myself in a not too big application).

Just be sure to have your tests running before starting.

Good luck.